# Arranging binary sequence atleast 5 zeros between every two 1's [Full answer provided - need an explanation ]

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Given $n$ 1's and $m$ 0's, how many ways to arrange them in a row that
> between every 2 1's there are at least 5 zeros?

**Solution:**
Number of binary sequences that are formed by $s$ 1's and $t$ 0's is
$\binom{s+t}{s}$.

For a binary sequence with atleast 5 zeros between every two 1's formed by $s$ 1's and $t+5(s-1)$ 0's

Example: 001011010 → 001**00000**01**00000**1**00000**010

We conclude that we have surjective and injective function then number of ways to arrange binary sequences from $s$ 1's and $t+5(s-1)$ 0's that between for every two 1's atleast 5 zeros is $\binom{s+t}{s}$

$\begin{cases}
 & s=n\\ 
 &  t= m+5(n-1)
\end{cases}$
$\Leftarrow \begin{cases}
 & n=s \\ 
 &  m= t+5(s-1)
\end{cases}$

we get $\binom{s+t}{s}$ = $\binom{n+m-5(n-1)}{n}$ =$\binom{m-4n+5}{n}$

**My question:**

After the example I don't understand anything about how it's solved, can I more elaboration please?

Answer (score 1):

They are making a correspondence between binary strings that have no restriction and binary strings where there are at least five $0$s between every pair of $1$s by replacing all the $1$s in the first except the last with $100000$ to get the second.  They demonstrate that forms a bijection, then compute the number of $0$s and $1$s in the resulting string.